# CocoaPods error while doing "pod install": [!] Invalid `Podfile` file: uninitialized constant Pod::Podfile::Flurry.

Tags: npm, react-native, cocoapods, flurry

I am trying to install Flurry for React Native using the npm [React Native Flurry Analytics](https://github.com/xxsnakerxx/react-native-flurry-analytics#react-native-flurry-analytics)

Here is my pod file:

```
target 'myApp' do

  pod Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurrySDK

end
```

and running `pod install` in the /ios directory of my React-Native project i get:

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: uninitialized constant Pod::Podfile::Flurry.
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I needed quotes around Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurrySDK.

It should look like this:

```
target 'myApp' do

  pod 'Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurrySDK'

end
```